# Starts with Symfony2 : No route found for "GET /"

Tags: php, symfony, installation

I just installed `Symfony2` on my Mac. My `web/config.php` works fine but when I go to the `web/app_dev.php` file, it shows me an error :

> No route found for "GET /" (from
>   "http://localhost:8888/Symfony/web/config.php")
>
> 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException

1 linked Exception: `ResourceNotFoundException`

> ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No
>   route found for "GET /" (from
>   "http://localhost:8888/Symfony/web/config.php")" at
>   .../Symfony/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 2059

I am following a tutorial and I am supposed to get this welcome page : [image: welcome_page]
Does anyone has an idea of what to do ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835645/symfony-2-fresh-install-no-url-works) post..

Comment: You didn't modified any file, right?

Comment: @DonCallisto no indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's because your demo route is equal to /app/example or something like that. Go to DefaultController in your AppBundle and change @Route parameter to single slash /